# Firebase Dynamic Links not being created and not opening app (flutter)

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I want my app to let users share posts through dynamic links. This is the function I use to create the link when a user presses share:

```
  static FirebaseDynamicLinks dynamicLinks = FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance;

  static Future<String> createDynamicPostLink(String owner, String id) async {
    String link;

    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://globemedia.me',
      link: Uri.parse('https://www.globemedia.me/?owner=$owner?id=$id'),
      androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
        packageName: "flutter.globemedia.me.globe_flutter",
        minimumVersion: 1,
      ),
      iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
        bundleId: "flutter.globemedia.me.globeFlutter",
        minimumVersion: '2',
      ),
    );

    final Uri url = await dynamicLinks.buildLink(parameters);

    link = url.toString();
    print(link);
    return link;
  }
```

That code follows all of the tutorials I've watched and follows the official flutter documentation. It should work, but although it prints a link, the dynamic links are not created in Firebase. I added "https://globemedia.me/home" as a new dynamic link from the console just to see if the deep linking works at all, and when opening the link on my iPhone, the "open app?" page shows up and when I press yes, it does work. This is how I check for deep links being opened in the background:

```
static Future<void> initDynamicLink(BuildContext context) async {
    dynamicLinks.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
      final Uri deepLink = dynamicLinkData.link;

      var isPost = deepLink.pathSegments.contains("post");

      if (isPost) {
        String owner = deepLink.queryParameters['owner']!;
        String id = deepLink.queryParameters['id']!;

        if (deepLink != null) {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SinglePostScreen(owner: owner, id: id)));
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }).onError((error) {
      print('onLink error');
      print(error.message);
    });
  }
```

This is how I check when the app is not in the background:

```
  _checkIfDeepLink() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
    await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

    if (initialLink != null) {
      final Uri deepLink = initialLink.link;

      var isPost = deepLink.pathSegments.contains("post");

      if (isPost) {
        String owner = deepLink.queryParameters['owner']!;
        String id = deepLink.queryParameters['id']!;

        print(owner + id);

        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SinglePostScreen(owner: owner, id: id)));
      }
    }
  }
```

What am I missing? It has to be an error specifically with creating the dynamic links because that's the only thing not working. This is not working on an android simulator or a physical iPhone so it's not just an issue on one platform.

Comment: Update: Since I was using "/post", I needed to add another prefix "https://globemedia.me/post" instead of just "https://globemedia.me".

Comment: Hi, it seems I have the same problem. Can you specify again what your solution was? I'm not sure to understand...